# Trying to include glfw library with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, dependencies, glfw

I'm trying to add glfw to my project but its not working. It builds with no problem but if I try to include GLFW/glfw3.h it says it can't find it.

cmake:

```
add_executable(gl_test main.cpp)

#GLFW

add_subdirectory(./glfw-3.3.4)

set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

set(OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE GLVND)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

if (OPENGL_FOUND)
    target_include_directories(gl_test PUBLIC ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(gl_test ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY})
endif()

target_link_libraries(gl_test glfw)
```

Any idea why its not working?

Comment: There's a few things "weird"  about your CMakeLists.txt, such as setting the GLFW constants *after* adding the glfw source, but that wouldn't cause your issue. It's the suspicious lack of `cmake_minimum_required()` and `project()` that piques my interest. This suggests that this CMakeLists.txt is part of a larger project. Maybe something upstream is interfering here?

Comment: I didnt include those in the code I posted here, I have them though